# When directly opening the website with hashtag (anchor-link) is not working - In angular 6?

Tags: hash, angular6, angular-routing

How can we do when the main website loads it needs to take to the particular place in to that page with using hashtag.

Ex: Normally my page loads with the url like https://helloapp.com/#/ in angular 6
Now if i use https://hellpapp.com/#gotothisplace/ needs to go the particular place in my website.

so to achieve this i am using

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<a [routerLink]="['']" fragment="gotothisplace"></a>
```

Comment: you have to specify your routes in `app-routing.module.ts`

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/8104/angular-router-tutorial